# Find documents in MongoDB where one element or elements in array field matches an element in other array

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, mongoose, multiple-matches

The query I've got so far:

```
const cities = await City.find({ names :  { $in: citiesArray }})
```

The field `names` are a `String` separated by commas `(e.g "A, B, C, D, E...")` 
The field `citiesArray` is a array `(e.g. ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", ...])`

How can I change this code to, let's say, return all documents that contain the first element in the names field `'A'`. That would do, of course, if any elements from the array match any of the elements from the string field names, which could be useful later, but for now, matching the first element will be enough.

Comment: This is doable but will not scale well at all. Is it a common operation? Why are you storing the different values consternated into a single string field?

Comment: This is just an example. In the future, I could use tags as field, such as PHP, Java, Node.js, and the same principle will apply.  So the question remains. And besides, if matches only the first value in the first array, will be enough for now.

Comment: "_I could use tags as field_" - why not store them as an array of strings though? The query is much simpler and it can efficiently use an index to perform and scale well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the `array` and generate a `new Regex` from each value in it:

```js
const citiesArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", ...];

const mapToRegex = array => array.map(val => new RegExp(val, 'i'));
const cities = await City.find({ names: { $in: mapToRegex(citiciesArray) } });
```

Or you can use the pipe-delimited `|` regex pattern:

```js
const citiesArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", ...];
const cities = await City.find({ names: { $regex: match.join("|"), $options: 'i' }});
```

I created a demo here with more examples that include the results for both ways to explain it better: [Demo Link](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/DiDMlnHHJRM)

Also, here is the documentation: [MongoDB Regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#-regex-vs.--pattern--syntax)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find is this:

```
const city = await City.findById({_id: req.params.id})
const names = city.cities.split(",")
const first = names[0]
const cities = await City.find({ names: new RegExp(first, 'i') })
```

It solves if I must match only the first value from the first array (from field cities). But this is not a good solution if later I try to expand to match all fields from first field of strings (separated by commas) and an array of itens